# Check exist field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question about elasticSearch. I want to save some data in elastic For example, I have several fields(age, name, color).
We save age=30,color=red, name=David
Now my question is this, If the next document is imported and all the fields are the same, I want the data not to be saved in Elastic and even if only one of them is different, it should be saved in it.
How can I implement it using the boolquery in Java language?

I tested matchAllQuery but I confuesd!!!!

Comment: You manage the id documents?

Comment: Every time when adding a new document, a new id is generated, that's why I have to compare the field I want to check if it exists or not with other fields.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to rely on the uniqueness of the _id field supported by Elasticsearch out-of-the-box. So, the only thing you need to do is to generate an _id that is uniquely bound to the minimum set of fields that define the uniqueness of a document. In your case, e.g., `PUT /index_name/_doc/30redDavid`, or - recommended - the output of a good hashing algorithm that takes as input `30redDavid`

Answer (score 0):

The match_all query would not work for your case because this query returns all indexed documents, the ideal is use a bool query and specify each of the fields that you are using.

Eg: `{    "query":{       "bool":{          "must":{             "term":{                "name":"David"             }          },          "should":[             {                "term":{                   "age":30                }             },             {                "term":{                   "color":"red"                }             }          ],          "minimum_should_match":2,          "boost":1.0       }    } }`

Comment: If the number of fields is large, should I write all the fields one by one?